# How to find smallest price in a array object collection with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am having an array of var calculation = []; that holds some object and each object has price associated with this. I need to find smallest price among that collection and need to remove that object form array collection. I am doing as following but no success how can i achive this?

```
while (chargedItems > 0) {
    currCustomziationPrice = currCustomziationPrice + Math.min.apply(Math, calculation.price); // 1
    chargedItems = chargedItems - 1;
    calculation.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, arr), 1);
    alert(currCustomziationPrice + "___" + chargedItems);
}
```

Comment: If calculation is an array, how does that : `calculation.price` return something? It should be `calculation[index].price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(arrayVariable, function() {
    var lowest = Math.min.apply(null, grid);
    var index = grid.indexOf(lowest);
    grid[index] += $(this).height();
}
```

Comment: But array of caculation has objects and each object has property price with this.. what your code doing i am not getting..